# How to name new worksheets based on values in array and copy associated values from original data set?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have data in columns P,Q,R. I would like to filter through R, and make a new Worksheet for each unique item in Column R. This new worksheet will also bring along the associated values in P and Q.

Thus far I have learned how to filter the data in R and put the unique values into an array. For each value in the array I made a new sheet named Array1(i) because I am unable to convert the value into a string for some reason. How can I do this in an optimized fashion such that I create a new sheet for each unique value in R and bring along the values in the same rows in P and Q as well? Here is my code:

Also, how do I declare the array dynamically rather than hard coding 50? How can I use a dynamic range for column R?

Note the values in the array will be something like 6X985

```
Sub testarray()
Dim TestRg As Excel.Range
Dim Array1(50) As Variant
Dim SheetName As String
Dim i, j, k As Integer
i = 1

Set TestRg = Range("R1:R36879")
TestRg.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True
For Each c In TestRg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Array1(i) = c.Value
    'SheetName = CStr(c.Value)
   Worksheets.Add.Name = i
    i = i + 1
Next c
j = i - 1
i = 1

Worksheets("Sheet1").ShowAllData
For Each c In Range("S3:S" & j)
    c.Value = Array1(i)
    i = i + 1

Next c
k = 1
For Each d In Range("T3:T" & j)
        d.Value = k
        k = k + 1
        Next d
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

The code itself is kind of advanced, I added comments to assist with understanding.  I hope it helps:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim xlCalc As XlCalculation
    Dim arrUnq() As Variant
    Dim strSheetName As String
    Dim UnqIndex As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set wsData = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rngData = wsData.Range("R1", wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp))

    'Disable application items to let code run faster
    With Application
        xlCalc = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    'Re-enable all the application items just in case there's an error
    On Error GoTo CleanExit

    'Get the list of unique values from rngData, sorted alphabetically
    'Put that list into the arrUnq array
    With Sheets.Add
        rngData.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , .Range("A1"), True
        .UsedRange.Sort .UsedRange, xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
        arrUnq = Application.Transpose(.Range("A2", .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value)
        .Delete
    End With

    For UnqIndex = LBound(arrUnq) To UBound(arrUnq)

        'Verify a valid worksheet name
        strSheetName = arrUnq(UnqIndex)
        For i = 1 To 7
            strSheetName = Replace(strSheetName, Mid(":\/?*[]", i, 1), " ")
        Next i
        strSheetName = Trim(Left(WorksheetFunction.Trim(strSheetName), 31))

        'Check if worksheet name already exists
        If Not Evaluate("ISREF('" & strSheetName & "'!A1)") Then
            'Sheet doesn't already exist, create sheet
            Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = strSheetName
        End If
        Set wsNew = Sheets(strSheetName)
        wsNew.UsedRange.Clear

        'Filter for the unique data
        With rngData
            .AutoFilter 1, arrUnq(UnqIndex)

            'Copy the data from columns P:R to the new sheet
            Intersect(wsData.Range("P:R"), .EntireRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wsNew.Range("A1")
        End With

    Next UnqIndex

    rngData.AutoFilter  'Remove any remaining filters

CleanExit:
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalc
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Description, , "Error: " & Err.Number
        Err.Clear
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks! I looked through the code extensively. Can you explain why you transposed the Unique Array?

Comment: That converts it from a 2-dimensional array to a 1-dimensional array.